# jQuery Heading text direction - firefox

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, firefox, jquery-ui-accordion

I have a heading in a jquery accordion which I have rotated to 'vertical' in my css. This is working in Chrome, but not in Firefox or Internet Explorer?

I have tried adding '!important' but it still wont display the rotation?

```
#contentAccordion{
     margin:0 auto;
     height:500px;
     width: 100%;


}

ul.accordion{
    list-style:none;   
    position:absolute;
    left: 1px;
    top:0px;
    font-family: Cambria, serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-style: italic;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    width: 100%;

}
ul.accordion li{
    float:right;
    width:115px;
    height:380px;
    display:block;
    border-right:2px solid #fff;
    border-bottom:2px solid #fff;
    background-color:#fff;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:center center;
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
    cursor:pointer;
    -moz-box-shadow:1px 3px 15px #555;
    -webkit-box-shadow:1px 3px 15px #555;
    box-shadow:1px 3px 15px #555;
}
ul.accordion li.bg1{
    background-image:url(http://www.fsi.lookinside.co.za/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/air.jpg);
}
ul.accordion li.bg2{
    background-image:url(http://www.fsi.lookinside.co.za/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/2.jpg);
}
ul.accordion li.bg3{
    background-image:url(http://www.fsi.lookinside.co.za/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/3.jpg);
}
ul.accordion li.bg4{
    background-image:url(http://www.fsi.lookinside.co.za/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/4.jpg);
}
ul.accordion li.bg5{
    background-image:url(http://www.fsi.lookinside.co.za/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/air.jpg);
}

ul.accordion li.bleft{
    border-left:2px solid #fff;
}
ul.accordion li .heading {
background-color: rgba(245, 240, 240, 0.65);
padding: 10px;
margin-top: 250px;
opacity: 0.6;
text-transform: uppercase;
font-style: normal;
font-weight: bold;
letter-spacing: 10px;
font-size: 25px;
color: rgb(12, 11, 11);
text-align: center;
text-shadow: -1px -1px 1px #ccc;
-webkit-transform: translatey(-100%) rotate(-90deg);
line-height: 80px;
height: 80px;
width: 280px;
margin-left: -100px;

}
ul.accordion li .description{
    position:absolute;
    width:260px;
    height:175px;
    bottom:0px;
    left:0px;
    display:none;
}
ul.accordion li .description h2{
    text-transform:uppercase;
    font-style:normal;
    font-weight:bold;
    letter-spacing:1px;
    font-size:45px;
    color:#444;
    text-align:left;
    margin:0px 0px 15px 20px;
    text-shadow:-1px -1px 1px #ccc;
}
ul.accordion li .description p{
    line-height:14px;
    margin:10px 22px;
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-style: italic;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-transform: none;
    letter-spacing: normal;
    line-height: 1.6em;
}
ul.accordion li .description a{
    position:absolute;
    bottom:5px;
    left:20px;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    font-style:normal;
    font-size:11px;
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#888;
}
ul.accordion li .description a:hover{
    color:#333;
    text-decoration:underline;
}

ul.accordion li .bgDescription{
    background:transparent url(http://www.fsi.lookinside.co.za/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/bgDescription.png) repeat-x top left;
    height:340px;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0px;
    left:0px;
    width:260px;
    display:none;
}

/* Vertical Accordion Style */

.container {
        width:100% !important;
        position:relative;
        margin:40px auto 0 auto;
        top: -17px;
        left: 0px;
}


.va-wrapper{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    position:absolute;
    overflow:hidden;
    background:#000;
        left: 0px;
}
.va-slice{
    cursor:pointer;
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    left:0px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.va-slice-1{
    background:#000 url(http://www.fsi.lookinside.co.za/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/Airfreight10.png) no-repeat center center;
}
.va-slice-2{
    background:#000 url(http://www.fsi.lookinside.co.za/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/Seafreight2.png) no-repeat center center;
}
.va-slice-3{
    background:#000 url(http://www.fsi.lookinside.co.za/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/Satellite.png) no-repeat center center;
}
.va-slice-4{
    background:#000 url(http://www.fsi.lookinside.co.za/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/Guarding11.png) no-repeat center center;
}
.va-slice-5{
    background:#000 url(http://www.fsi.lookinside.co.za/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/Move3.png) no-repeat center center;
}
.va-slice-6{
    background:#000 url(http://www.fsi.lookinside.co.za/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/Investigations2.png) no-repeat center center;
}
.va-slice-7{
    background:#000 url(http://www.fsi.lookinside.co.za/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/transport2.png) no-repeat center center;
}
.va-slice-color-1{
    background-color:#97c5eb;
}
.va-slice-color-2{
    background-color:#68ace5;
}
.va-slice-color-3{
    background-color:#0072cf;
}
.va-slice-color-4{
    background-color:#0039a6;
}
.va-slice-color-5{
    background-color:#00338e;
}
.va-slice-color-6{
    background-color:#002c76;
}
.va-slice-color-7{
    background-color:#002144;
}
.va-title{
    font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed', sans-serif;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    font-size:40px;
    margin-left:20px;
    color:#fff;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 1px white;
}
.va-content{
    display:none;
    margin-left:25px;


}
.va-slice p{
    font-size: 22px;
    font-style: italic;
    font-family:Georgia, serif;
}
.va-slice ul{
    margin-top:20px;
}
.va-slice ul li{
    float:left;
    margin:0px 2px;
}
.va-slice ul li a{
    color:#000;
    background:#eede2f;
    padding:3px 6px;
    font-size:14px;
    font-family:'PT Sans', sans-serif;
    text-transform:uppercase;
}
.va-slice ul li a:hover{
    background:#000;
    color:#fff;
    text-shadow:none;
}
.va-nav span{
    width:40px;
    height:25px;
    background:transparent url(http://www.fsi.lookinside.co.za/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/prev.png) no-repeat center center;
    position:absolute;
    top:-35px;
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-20px;
    text-indent:-9000px;
    opacity:0.7;
    cursor:pointer;

    z-index:100;
}
.va-nav span.va-nav-next{
    background-image:url(http://www.fsi.lookinside.co.za/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/next.png);
    top:auto;
    bottom:-35px;
}
.va-nav span:hover{
    opacity:1.0;
}
```

Comment: `-webkit` only works for WebKit browsers; the clue is very much in the name. You may need to use the vendor prefixes: `moz`, `-o`, `-ms` and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only use `-webkit-transform: translatey(-100%) rotate(-90deg);`

You forgot other vendor prefixes : `-moz-` for firefox, `-ms-` for IE, etc...

If you want to  know what browsers support a property : http://caniuse.com/#search=transform
Apparently, you don't need the -moz- prefix for that propert, Firefox has already implemented it.

Best practice: always define the rule without vendor prefix at the bottom :

```
-webkit-transform: translatey(-100%) rotate(-90deg);
transform: translatey(-100%) rotate(-90deg);
```

That way, it will still work in the future, even if the browser removes its prefix support.

Comment: Thank you very much. It is now working in firefox. would I insert -ms- into it for it to work in IE?

Comment: As you can see here : http://caniuse.com/#search=transform IE 10 supports it, IE 9 needs `-ms-`, IE7 and below doesn't support `transform`. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you. great site. I have now tried this but now my text is dissapearing all together in IE?   `-ms-transform: scale(0.8) rotate(90deg);
-ms-transform-origin: 0% 100%;`